# Need to add 50 users with specific uid range, identified userid list, custom user comment and custom primary group

Tags: linux, scripting, centos, user-accounts

I am using centOS in an administration class, I do not want all the answers as I know that is taboo here for understandable reasons. But I would appreciate a nudge in the correct direction with a little explanation along the way.

I am trying to write a shell script to read my roster of 50 userid's named user_list and assign a UID in the range of 5000 to 5049. Providing a comment of "Regular system user", and assign each user to a predefined primary group of system_users.

I have the following command in mind:

a counter initialized at 5000 to keep the UID range in something of a while loop

a counter initialized at 0 to begin from the beginning of my user_list file to the last entry

```
for i in `cat user_list|cut -d" " -f1 (this file only has a single column of userid's ranging 0 through 49 so only one field needed)`

echo $i
grep_output=`grep $i /etc/passwd`
if [ -z $grep_output ]; then

useradd -u $(counting number from the range above) -g system_users -c "Regular system user" -s /local/bin/sudosh $(user# from user_id file)
```

and I would have this command repeat for each user listed in my user_list file

I would be glad to provide more info upon request. I struggle at loops so was wanting a little assistance.

Comment: It's not taboo, it happens all the time.

Comment: I take alot of pride in not stealing the asnwers, but this has me stumped, I had to delete a lot of account and directories attempting this so far

Comment: Now is a great time to learn about the virtual machine snapshot feature of whatever hypervisor you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a global direction, but:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=0
cat user_list | while read name; do
    grep_output=$(grep "$name" /etc/passwd)
    if [ -z "$grep_output" ]; then
        echo useradd -u $((5000+n++)) -g system_user -c "Regular User" \
                    "$name"
    fi
done
```

There is two key elements you were probably missing. First I used `read` ... to read line of file (assuming there is no space in the user names). Then, more important, I used *bash arithmetics* to perform calculation: `$((5000 + n++))`. The notation `n++` is reminiscence of *C* and is called a [post increment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators). That is it takes the value of `n` to perform calculation, and *then* increases it. <sub>I fixed some quoting too</sub>

The above code produces that result:

```
sh$ cat user_list 
sylvain
john
paul
george
ringo
sh$ ./l.sh 
useradd -u 5000 -g system_user -c Regular User john
useradd -u 5001 -g system_user -c Regular User paul
useradd -u 5002 -g system_user -c Regular User george
useradd -u 5003 -g system_user -c Regular User ringo
```

Comment: This seems to fit my task parameters. I will test in my virtual environment and see how it goes. I always seem to get hung up on how to setup a loop and control the iterations. I used looping logic to create the list and was tempted to try and have the list to be generated and the immediately flow into the useradd function, but saw that to be too problematic.

Answer (score 0):

This my simple script version, without cat on file and while read

```
   #!/bin/bash

   uarray=($(seq 5000 5049))

   n=0

   for i in $(<userlist);do
        if ! grep $i /etc/passwd >/dev/null; then
             echo "useradd -u ${uarray[$n]} -g system_user -c "Regular User" $i"
        fi
        ((n++))
   done
```

Output

```
    bash create.bash
    useradd -u 5000 -g system_user -c Regular User sylvain
    useradd -u 5001 -g system_user -c Regular User john
    useradd -u 5002 -g system_user -c Regular User paul
    useradd -u 5003 -g system_user -c Regular User george
    useradd -u 5004 -g system_user -c Regular User ringo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this just helped me solve a problem 6 years later :)